# Requesting tokens to custom URL. OIDC and @auth0/auth0-angular

Tags: angular, token, openid-connect, auth0

I'm working on an Angular app with OIDC authentication. I'm using @auth0/auth0-angular as an OIDC client. I set up an auth0 server for testing purposes, and it works like a charm. Now I'm trying to point my app to the prod server, and I'm facing the following problem:

I configured my domain: http://jmarfia.com/oauth2. My OIDC server expects to receive token requests at http://jmarfia.com/oauth2/token. By default, the token request goes to domain + /oauth/token (http://jmarfia.com/oauth2/oauth/token), and there are no token server there. How can I make my app send the token request to http://jmarfia.com/oauth2/token?

I tried several configurations on AuthModule.forRoot, and nothing is working for me. I need some guidance or advice, thank you.

My last My last configuration was:

```
import { AuthModule, AuthConfig } from '@auth0/auth0-angular';

const authConfig: AuthConfig = {
  domain: 'YOUR_DOMAIN',
  clientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
  audience: 'YOUR_API_IDENTIFIER',
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [AuthModule.forRoot(authConfig)],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. It's best to provide some code, you said that you've tried several configurations of AuthModule, could you please post the latest one? Without it, it's difficult to give you a correct advice

Comment: Hi! you are right! 

I'll edit mi op with some code. Thanks!